# Assign a vector to a specific existing row of data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I've been looking through tutorials and documentation, but have not figured out how to assign a vector of values for all columns to one existing row in a `data.table`.

I start with an empty `data.table` that has already the correct number of columns and rows:

```
dt <- data.table(matrix(nrow=10, ncol=5))
```

Now I calculate some values for one row outside of the `data.table` and place them in a vector `vec`, e. g.:

```
vec <- rnorm(5)
```

How could I assign the values of vec to e. g. the first row of the `data.table` while achieving a good performance (since I also want to fill the other rows step by step)?

Comment: Since you are using `data.table` for performance reason (as stated in comment to one answer below) I think adding (many) rows again and again is **not** efficient at all since the `data.table` (like `data.frame`) is  column store, not a row store (which means whenever you add a row different locations in the memory must be accessed). What is the reason (algorithm) that requires you to add rows?

Comment: I am creating a very large empty table (11 thousand rows x 8 thousand columns), and am then doing some calculations to create a vector that I then use to fill this table in row by row. I thought using data.table might make this faster than if I used a matrix or a dataframe.

Comment: OK, I think `data.table` is faster using it this way since you preallocate the required memory (table size) and overwrite the rows by reference (if you use the answer of Richard with the `:=` operator) since this solution does NOT copy the whole data just because you modify one value. May I edit your question to clarify the exact use case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to get the correct column types, as the `NA` matrix you've created is logical. The column types won't be magically changed by assigning numerics to them.

```
dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]
```

Then you can change the first row's values with

```
dt[1, names(dt) := as.list(vec)]
```

That said, if you begin with a numeric matrix you wouldn't have to change the column types.

```
dt <- data.table(matrix(numeric(), 10, 5))
dt[1, names(dt) := as.list(vec)]
```