# Efficient data table/ frame/ tibble/ other aggregation in R

Tags: r, data.table, tibble

I have a data.table of values for which I compute summarized statistics in a loop, and seek to aggregate the summarized results for additional processing. However, the loop processing time is unexpectedly lengthy as a result of the aggregation, and I'm seeking a faster solution.

The method very much resembles the approach discussed here ([Assign a vector to a specific existing row of data table in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633187/assign-a-vector-to-a-specific-existing-row-of-data-table-in-r)).

Code (<strike>slightly abridged for readability, but material components preserved</strike> illustrative):

```
library(data.table);
x <- data.table(matrix(double(),nrow=10000,ncol=120));
system.time({for (i in NROW(x):1) {
    m <- matrix(rnorm(8*15),nrow=8,ncol=15);
}});
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.165   0.006   0.171 
system.time({for (i in NROW(x):1) {
    m <- matrix(rnorm(8*15),nrow=8,ncol=15);
    as.list(t(m[1:8,]));
}});
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.245   0.001   0.249
system.time({for (i in NROW(x):1) {
    m <- matrix(rnorm(8*15),nrow=8,ncol=15);
    x[i,] <- as.list(t(m[1:8,]));
}});
#   user  system elapsed 
# 36.227   0.682  37.529
```

```
# Obtain input data.table
inputdt <- fread('filename');

# Preallocate summary statistics aggregate
sumstatsdt <- data.table(matrix(double(),nrow=10000,ncol=120));

# Loop over input data.table (the *apply suite not suitable for mypkg::calcstats())
for (i in NROW(inputdt):1) {
    # Produce a matrix of summary statistics for the row (of type double)
    sumstat_matrix <- mypkg::calcstats(inputdt,...);

    # Aggregate the summary statistics (where "a","b","c",... are matrix row names of ordered statistics)
    # >>>> This is the operation that leads to lengthy execution time
    sumstatsdt[i,] <- as.list(t(sumstat_matrix[c("a","b","c",...),]));
};
```

The input data.table contains 10,000 observations with 8 attributes, and there are a total of 1.2 million summary statistics to be stored (each of type 'double'). When commenting out the last line in the loop that  performs the aggregation, the total processing time is around **24 sec**. When run with the aggregation, total processing time increases to **34 min**.

I have tried to use comparable code with `data.frame` and `cbind()` with loosely similar performance results (have not had a chance to try the  `tidyverse` suite). Recognize that deep copy operations will be somewhat slower, though the magnitude of the execution time difference given the relatively small dataset seems to indicate a different issue.

Running R v3.4.4, data.table v1.11.4 on recent Fedora install. Memory usage is negligible (less than 3% of system RAM in use during R script execution). One of the 2.1GHz CPU processors with affinity to the R session runs at nearly 100% for the duration of the script execution. There are no other processes associated with that core and remaining cores are largely idle. (**NB**: Illustrative code run in KVM guest on different machine)

Sidenote: Also curious as to why CPU bottleneck manifests in what otherwise appears to be a memory issue.

Appreciate the time, and happy to provide additional info as useful.

#### Edit [2018.10.31]

- Include illustrative code requested by [42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1855677/42)

Comment: Abridged code???

Comment: correct - related to preparation of other arguments to the package function and listing out all row names of the matrix. Nothing omitted that would affect the ability to review the code in light of the question raised. Thx

Comment: It’s pretty common that questioners _do_ omit something that is critical. Trying to guess at what that might be is generally unproductive. Hence the requirement for a [MCVE].

Comment: No doubt, and hopefully the reproducible code in the edit proves more useful. Please adjust the number of rows in 'x' to scale timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your machine seems about twice as fast as mine, but still I get an almost 15-fold improvement for sequential assignment to particular rows of a data.table object by using the data.table operator `:=` instead of `<-`. I'm not sure, but suspect that using `<-` commits you to depending on the usual R step of creation of an intermediate temporary copy, so it's likely that the `:=` method is also more memory efficient:

```
?`:=`

 system.time({for (i in NROW(x):1) {
     m <- matrix(rnorm(8*15),nrow=8,ncol=15);
     x[i , (1:120) := as.list(t(m))] } })

 #   user  system elapsed 
 # 4.390   0.096   4.486 


system.time({for (i in NROW(x):1) {
     m <- matrix(rnorm(8*15),nrow=8,ncol=15);
     x[i , ] <- as.list(t(m)) } })

#   user  system elapsed 
# 67.963  15.573  83.572
```

Regular R is  a single thread process unless you install one of the "after-market" mods like MRAN.

Comment: Much appreciated, and I can confirm similar efficiencies on my machine. Marking this as answer as it successfully reduces the processing time to within a reasonable duration for my particular problem set. All the best.